# Calculating Rate in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'Code':['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO'],       
        'Val': [1000, 2000, 5000,7000, 8000]})
    #df['Diff rate'] = df.Val.diff()
    df
```

I want to introduce a new column 'Diff Rate' that has the difference between the (current Val -Previous Val)/Current Val. How can I go about it? 
Expected values are: `NaN,0.5,0.6,0.2857,0.125` in the `Diff Rate` Column
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Diff rate'] = df["Val"].diff() / df["Val"]
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
  Code   Val  Diff rate
0  ABC  1000        NaN
1  DEF  2000   0.500000
2  GHI  5000   0.600000
3  JKL  7000   0.285714
4  MNO  8000   0.125000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
val = df['Val'].tolist()

diff = [None]

for i in range(1, len(val)):
    diff.append((val[i]-val[i-1])/val[i])
```

The output will be

```
[None, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2857142857142857, 0.125]
```

```
df['diff_rate'] = diff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` to specify the number of periods you want the difference to be of:

```
df['Diff rate'] = (df['Val']- df['Val'].shift(periods=1))/df['Val']
```

result:

```
  Code   Val  Diff rate
0  ABC  1000        NaN
1  DEF  2000   0.500000
2  GHI  5000   0.600000
3  JKL  7000   0.285714
4  MNO  8000   0.125000
```